# Transfer dates between two jsp immediately

Tags: jsp

I have problem, how to transfer dates betwen two jsp pages.
in order, i have JSP page with four input text and imgage with hiperlink. 
The first three inputtexts are name, surname, street and fourth inputtext is connection with image with hiperlink. When the user click img, it will be open new window with table. There selects the appropriate field, selects and clicks. then the value from that page should be write down in the fourth input text. How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe you should post some code to help us understand the problem

Comment: i don't know how to start. i have 4 input text on one page and checkbox on second page

Answer (score 0):

If you want the window that gets opened to put a value into a field in the first window you have to do several things.

1) The windows have to be identified. One easy way to do this is to assign a window name in Javascript.

```
window.name = "MainWindow" // set the name of the main window
```

then, something similar for the child window:

```
var myWindow = window.open(url, "MsgWindow", "width = 200, height = 100");
```

2) The `url`, which is the first argument to `open()`, loads the contents of the table that you described.

3) The click function on the table actually will write the value back to the `MainWindow` into the fourth field. Then it will close `MsgWindow`.